# Handling Ticks in Mathematica`s Charts

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Please consider :

```
dalist = {{379, 219, 228, 401}, {387, 239, 230, 393},      
          {403, 238, 217, 429}, {377, 233, 225, 432}}

BarChart[dalist, 
         Frame -> True, 
         FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}]
```

[image]

I can`t figure out the way to deal with the ticks themselves and the range (the numbers). I would like to see the Range but not the ticks like the below :

[image]

**EDIT :**

Having solved some problem, it seems I created new ones.
To Summarize, I would like to see :
TicksLabel but not the Ticks (solved)
FrameLabel but not the Frame.

The Below shall illustrate the problem. FrameStyle control the Frame Label. 
So applying opacity[0] to FrameStyle to hide the frame hides the frame Label.

```
BarChart[Range[10],
 ChartStyle -> Black,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"Why?", None}, {"Because !", None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1],
 FrameStyle -> Opacity[0],

 PlotLabel -> Style["Bonjour", Bold, 16, Opacity[1]],
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12, Opacity[1]],
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ticks and FrameTicks have optional more complex syntax, where each tick can be specified as `{x,label,{length_inside,length_outside}}`

So to have ticks labels without ticks, specify the second pair of numbers as two zeros.
To replicate the ticks in your example, you would use

```
FrameTicks->{{Table[{j,j,{0,0}},{j,0,300000,50000}],None},
 {Table[{k,k,{0,0}},{k,2010,2015}],None}}
```

For BarCharts, the bars are at 1, 2, 3... x-positions, so this needs to be:

```
FrameTicks->{{Table[{j,j,{0,0}},{j,0,300000,50000}],None},
 {Table[{k,k+2009,{0,0}},{k,1,6}],None}}
```

As requested in comments, if you want numbers but no ticks and no frame, add:

```
FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]
```

**EDIT** And use `Style` on any frame labels.

End result:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 300000}, {10}]
BarChart[data, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{j, j, {0, 0}}, {j, 0, 300000, 50000}], 
 None}, {Table[{k, k + 2009, {0, 0}}, {k, 1, 10}], None}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0],
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["Why?", Opacity[1]],  None}, 
   {Style["Axes", Opacity[1]], None}}]
```

[image]

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132794/how-to-choose-the-numbers-shown-on-the-axes-of-a-plot-in-mathemetica/7135127#7135127) might help illuminate.

Comment: C@Verbia, thank You,is there a way to have only the Ticks labels, no ticks and no axes ?

Comment: @500, yes, `FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]`.

Comment: @Verveia, I loose my FrameLabels turning the opacity down. So Ideally, I would have Frame Labels and the ticks Label.Any way ?

Comment: @500: Then you also need to set the `LabelStyle` option (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LabelStyle.html)

Comment: +1 for `FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]`

Comment: @Verbeia, I don`t know if I am not missing something obvious but for me FrameStyle still controls the FrameLabel opacity despite some LabelStyle Directive. Example : BarChart[Range[10],
 ChartStyle -> Black,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"Why?", None}, {"Axes", None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1],
 FrameStyle -> Opacity[0],
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Bonjour", Bold, 16, Opacity[1], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, 12, Opacity[1], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
 ImageSize -> 400]

Comment: @500: FrameLabel -> {{Style["Why?", Opacity[1]], 
   None}, {Style["Axes", Opacity[1]], None}}

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for `ChartLabels`:

```
BarChart[dalist, ChartLabels -> Placed[Flatten@dalist, Below], 
                 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}},
                 Frame -> True, 
                 Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately `ChartLabels` only works for bar charts, pie chartts etc. Ticks works for line plots as well.