# labeling a plot in increments of pi

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose the numbers  shown on the axes of a plot in mathemetica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132794/how-to-choose-the-numbers-shown-on-the-axes-of-a-plot-in-mathemetica)

How can I create a plot of a function where the scale will show things in terms of pi (or any other constant for that matter)?

i.e. under the ticks in the axis it will show 0, pi/2, pi/4 etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Ticks -> {Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/4], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you mean by *labeling* and *scale* is indeed the Ticks option of Plot. You can specify them by hand or use Table to create the values you want to use

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/4}], {-1, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]